# List values in multi-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been working on this a while. I see multi-dimensional arrays in php are not that easy. 
Here is my code:

```
      while (list($key,$value) = each ($x))
        {
        Print "$key  => $value\n<br>\n";
        }
```

This works well to display the keys of the main array. what I get is :

```
visitors => Array 
actions => Array 
actions-average => Array 
time-average => Array 
pages-entrance => Array
```

What I want is the visitors and the value (number of visitors), value of actions, etc.
I want to then save the value in Mysql. Some I will have to convert from a string to and int or date.

I need to list one more level deep. But I cannot see how to do this. 
--------------Added -----------
So what I have is an array of arrays. I need to step through each array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you try [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) ?

if you need more control over formatting then embedded loops as suggested by @Nick is the best option. Although it would be more natural and safer to use foreach loops rather than while.

```
foreach($x as $key => $value){
  foreach( $value as $key2 => $value2){
    print "$key $key2 => $value2\n<br />\n";
  }
}
```

see [PHP manual: each](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) , there is a "caution" frame.

**EDIT 1**
*I update sample code above for 2 day array.*

It seems your array has more than 2 dimension. Then you should use recursion.

```
function my_print_r($x,$header="")
{
  foreach($x as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value))
      my_print_r($value,$header . $key .  " " );
    else
      print "$header $key2 => $value2\n<br />\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats closer.      What I get is '2011-06-07 => Array 
     2011-06-07 => Array 
     2011-06-07 => Array 
     2011-06-07 => Array 
     2011-06-07 => Array 
     2011-06-07 => Array'

Comment: Btw I dont see how to use Print_ with this function. If I do print_r on the array ($x) it dumps everything to the screen. This is helpful to see that array is working, but id does not solve my problem.

Comment: I was just pointing you to print_r in case you were not aware of it. As @Bob_Gneu suggested, var_dump() is also good to know

Comment: I used this method. What was very confusing is some of the arrays had only 1 element and some had many. So it looked like there was a loop problem, but really there was one one count in the loop. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

the best way is var_dump($arr);

```
<?php

var_dump($_SERVER);

?>
```

with output that includes types, string length, and will iterate over objects as well.

Since you want to iterate over an array, give foreach a try:

```
foreach ($arr as $el)
{
    // ... Work with each element (most useful for non associative arrays, or linear arrays)
}

// or

foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
    // ... Work with $key and $value pairs (most useful for hashes/associative arrays)
}
```

Comment: Var dump does show me the entire array. But I need to se it one at a time to do a conversion from string to int. or from string to date. Then I can insert it into the database.

Comment: very interesting. I think this is the track I will need.

Answer (score 1):

Try loops like this code:

```
$arrA=array("a", "b", "c");
$arrB=array("x", "y", "z");
$x=array("visitors" => $arrA, "actions" => $arrB);
foreach($x as $key => $value)
{
   foreach($value as $v)   
      echo "$key  => $v<br>\n";
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
visitors  => a<br> 
visitors  => b<br> 
visitors  => c<br> 
actions  => x<br> 
actions  => y<br> 
actions  => z<br
```

Comment: @Joe: Please see above output it has generated. If it still doesn't work for you, please post your complete code here and I will be happy to fix that.

Comment: this is my complete code. I have an ajax call that loads everything into a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

/ / . . . here, we take variable $company for nested array and in this variable we put 2 employee id and its called multi-dimensional array and we take $company variable to assign the associative array with keys so we print the output with keys

$company=[

```
$emp=[1,"neha","employee",12000,30000],

$emp1=[2,"moni","manager",12000],
```

];

$company=["first" => $emp,"second" => $emp1];

foreach($company as $key => $value)
{

echo "$key ";

```
foreach($value as $v1){
     
    echo "$v1";
}
```

}

output :-

employee    ID      name         designation       salary     bonus

first       1       neha          employee      12000     30000

second      2       moni           manager      12000