# Print PHP Mutlidimensional Array as HTML List

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have the following PHP array:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'channels' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'INFORMATIONEN' => 
    array (
      0 => 'welcome',
      1 => 'rules',
      2 => 'contact',
    ),
     'NEWS' => 
    array (
      0 => '✉news',
      1 => 'videos',
    ),
     'TEAM' => 
    array (
      0 => '♠team-lounge',
      1 => 'coding',
      2 => 'bottest',
      3 => 'Besprechung',
      4 => '♠Team Lounge'
    ),
     'LIVE' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Live Stream 1',
      1 => 'Live Stream 2',
    ),
     'RECORD' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Aufnahme 1',
      1 => 'Aufnahme 2',
    ),
     'TK' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Diff',
    ),
     'USER' => 
    array (
      0 => 'lounge-1',
      1 => 'lounge-2',
      2 => 'lounge-3',
      3 => 'Lounge 1',
      4 => 'Lounge 2',
      5 => 'Lounge 3',
    ),
     'Support' => 
    array (
      0 => 'supportticket',
    ),
     'AFK' => 
    array (
      0 => 'AFK',
    ),
  )),
))
```

Thats the output of the following command:

```
echo '<pre>' . var_export($decodedChannels, true) . '</pre>';
```

That's a channel list of a discord server, which I'd like to display on a website.

What it should be displayed like is basically as a nested unordered list something like:

```
<ul>
    <li>INFORMATIONEN</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Welcome</li>
            <li>rules</li>
            <li>contact</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>NEWS</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>News</li>
            <li>Videos</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And so on for the other array parts of course. Basically it should look like in discord...

I searched a lot and found various solutions with `foreach` loops, different ideas and everything, but nothing worked... Either I only got the first layer of the array or only the keys or other issues...

Can anybody point me to the right idea to solve the problem?

Comment: The magic word is `recursion`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller yes, I've tried that, like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24865996/3375021 or here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260587/3375021... but it doesn't work for me...

Comment: What have you tried, what doesnt work for you? You literally have to copy the function `ToUl` as mentioned in your link and pass the array to the function. It creates everything except one additional `li` for like `'INFORMATIONEN'`.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal the only result I get copy pasting the`ToUl` function is the number 1.. nothing else.. no elements at all...for whatever reason..(inside a `ul`, without an `li`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to nest it. You have some unusual requirement of title listing, but this should work as you expect.

```
$data = array(
    'INFORMATIONEN' =>
        array(
            0 => 'welcome',
            1 => 'rules',
            2 => 'contact',
        ),
    'NEWS'          =>
        array(
            0 => '✉news',
            1 => 'videos',
        ),
    'TEAM'          =>
        array(
            0 => '♠team-lounge',
            1 => 'coding',
            2 => 'bottest',
            3 => 'Besprechung',
            4 => '♠Team Lounge'
        ),
    'LIVE'          =>
        array(
            0 => 'Live Stream 1',
            1 => 'Live Stream 2',
        ),
    'RECORD'        =>
        array(
            0 => 'Aufnahme 1',
            1 => 'Aufnahme 2',
        ),
    'TK'            =>
        array(
            0 => 'Diff',
        ),
    'USER'          =>
        array(
            0 => 'lounge-1',
            1 => 'lounge-2',
            2 => 'lounge-3',
            3 => 'Lounge 1',
            4 => 'Lounge 2',
            5 => 'Lounge 3',
        ),
    'Support'       =>
        array(
            0 => 'supportticket',
        ),
    'AFK'           =>
        array(
            0 => 'AFK',
        ),
);

function listArray($array) {
    echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        echo "<li>";
        if(is_array($value)) {
            listArray($value);
        } else {
            echo $value;
        }
        echo "</li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
}

foreach($data as $key => $array) {
    echo "<ul>\n";
    echo "<li>$key</li>\n";
    echo "<li>";
    listArray($array);
    echo "</li>\n";
    echo "</ul>\n";
}
```

This gives this HTML output

```
<ul>
    <li>INFORMATIONEN</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>welcome</li>
            <li>rules</li>
            <li>contact</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>NEWS</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>✉news</li>
            <li>videos</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>TEAM</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>♠team-lounge</li>
            <li>coding</li>
            <li>bottest</li>
            <li>Besprechung</li>
            <li>♠Team Lounge</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>LIVE</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Live Stream 1</li>
            <li>Live Stream 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>RECORD</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Aufnahme 1</li>
            <li>Aufnahme 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>TK</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Diff</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>USER</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>lounge-1</li>
            <li>lounge-2</li>
            <li>lounge-3</li>
            <li>Lounge 1</li>
            <li>Lounge 2</li>
            <li>Lounge 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Support</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>supportticket</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>AFK</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>AFK</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. for some reason however, I don't get the keys displayed, so I only get the sub elements but not the parents (the categories from discord)... also, on the very top, I get "channels", because its the root of the array, can I somehow grab everything underneath that?

Comment: Try `$data = $yourObject->channels`. I could not rebuild the stdClass, so I converted to array for convinience. You also can cast object to array like `$data = (array)$yourObject; var_dump($data['channels'])`.

Comment: yep, thats it! :) Thanks a lot! :)